# multiple activecheckboxlists in yii from the same model on the same page

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have a pages with multiple activeCheckBoxLists which are actually generated in a foreach loop.  The issue that I am having is that each list is generated with the same name's and id's as every other generated list.  I need a way to either send an iteration or something into the  id's and name's so that they are unique.

When I use jquery to select the first item of the list it selects the first item of every list.

Here is the code that generates the lists.

```
// collect all filter titles (level == 0, parent == 0)
$topLevelFilterTitles = $hsf->findAllByAttributes(array('level'=>'0','parent_id'=>'0'));
foreach($topLevelFilterTitles as $filterTitle):
  // with each filter title find all children (level == 1, parent == filter title id)
  echo "<div class='half menu split'>";
  echo "<p class='uppercase-text filter-name'>" . $filterTitle->title . "</p>";
  $filterOptions = $hsf->findAllByAttributes(
     array(
    'level'=>'1',
    'parent_id'=>$filterTitle->id,
     )
  );
  $list = CHtml::listData($filterOptions,'filter_name','title');
  echo CHtml::activeCheckBoxList(
     $hsf,  // model
 'filter_name',
 $list
  );
  echo "</div>";
endforeach;
```

The generated lists show up as follows

```
<div class="halfmenu split">
   <p class="uppercase-text filter-name">Filter Name R</p>
   <input id="ytHardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name" type="hidden" value="" name="HardwareSearchFiltering[filter_name]" />
   <input id="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_0" value="r_value0" type="checkbox" name="HardwareSearchFiltering[filter_name][]" /> 
   <label for="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_0">r_name0</label><br/>
   <input id="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_1" value="r_value1" type="checkbox" name="HardwareSearchFiltering[filter_name][]" />
   <label for="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_1">r_name1</label>
</div>
<div class="halfmenu split">
   <p class="uppercase-text filter-name">Filter Name T</p>
   <input id="ytHardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name" type="hidden" value="" name="HardwareSearchFiltering[filter_name]" />
   <input id="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_0" value="t_value0" type="checkbox" name="HardwareSearchFiltering[filter_name][]" /> 
   <label for="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_0">t_name0</label><br/>
   <input id="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_1" value="t_value1" type="checkbox" name="HardwareSearchFiltering[filter_name][]" />
   <label for="HardwareSearchFiltering_filter_name_1">t_name1</label><br/>
</div>
```

I need (preferably) the ID to be different between lists, but even if I could get the name different that would be a start.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add htmloptions to the activeCheckBoxList as indicated in the [API documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBoxList-detail). In your case I reckon you could do something like this:

```
echo CHtml::activeCheckBoxList(
    $hsf,  // model
    'filter_name',
    $list, array(
        // Here you could use your filterTitle id or any other
        // variable that will make your checkbox unique
        'id'   => 'chk_'.$filterTitle->id,
        'name' => 'chk_'.$filterTitle->id
    )
);
```

The Htmloptions are the 4th parameter in the instantiation of activeCheckBoxList as an array. Look at the API!

Comment: That worked!   I thought about doing that but I wasn't sure it would work, I don't know why I just didn't try it before.  Thanks for the help!